# Unique value using explode in PHP

Tags: php

The value in `tag_arr` should be unique:

```
<?php foreach ($all_metal as $key => $new_metal) :
    $tags_arr1 = explode(',', $new_metal['metal']); 
    if(isset($_GET['metal'])) :
          if(in_array($tags_arr1[0],$_GET['metal'])) : 
              $check5='checked="checked"';
          else : 
              $check5="";
          endif;
    endif;                                
?>
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting and clarify your question. e.g. what's you're input, what's your expected output and what's your code?

Comment: Try - `$tags_arr1 = array_unique(explode(',', $new_metal['metal']));`

Comment: Thnku for your reply... i tried it bt it was not working  @Sougata Bose

Comment: What is in `$new_metal['metal']`?

Comment: $all_metal=$db->query("SELECT DISTINCT `metal` FROM `products` WHERE `status` = 1 AND `metal` !='' GROUP BY `metal`");

Answer (score 0):

One example.

Read comments for step by step explanation.

```
<?php

/* A string to explode */
$string = 'test3,test1,test2,test1,test4,test3,test2';

/* Explode the string */
$array = explode(',', $string);

$result = array();

/* Iterate through all elements and save all unique values in the result array */
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
    if (!in_array($array[$i], $result))
        $result[] = $array[$i];

/* Unset array */
unset($array);

/* Sort result array ascending by value */
sort($result);

/* Show result */
print_r($result);

?>
```

Comment: How about `$results = array_unique(explode(',', $string))`?

Comment: It's a much better approach using array_unique, I am not too familiar with all the available functions.